# How to create GSon object for Json response

Tags: android

i am using Volley with Gson in my Application.From server i got json response.
But i dont know how to change Gson Object.Please any one help me.

This is my json Response

```
{"Master":"UserMaster","Field":["name","id"],"Data":[["Suman",1],["Suman",2]],
"ErrorCode":"0"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ . Copy paste your response in this website. Select schema as "Json" and Annotation style as "GSON" . This will generate a response class needed for GSON.

Then parsing the response into GSON is straight forward.

```
Gson gson = new Gson()    
YourReponseClass object  =  gson.fromJson(json, YourReponseClass);
```

This will create the needed response object for you

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class based on your json file

```
class MyModel{

    @SerializedName("Master")
    private String msater;
    @SerializedName("Field")
    private List<Fileds>filedList;


    class Filed{
         @SerializedName("name")
         private String name;

         @SerializedName("id")
         private int id;
    }


}
```

Then create an object of your model class inside your Activity, where the response is getting as like below.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
MyModel object =gson.fromJson(response.toString(), MyModel.class);
```

Volley response will get as an object. convert the object to sting and pass a a parameter to gson.